# Canvas Pixels Error

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following code:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(130, 0);
ctx.lineTo(130, 150);
ctx.stroke();
```

I've got a little messed up with the pixels and rotating the draw / line.
Let me explain, I've got normal canvas code, but rotate is not working correctly. I've tried playing a little with the numbers but I still can't get the angles I want since I can make only 180 rotation and not 270 (More or less).

Here is an image to explain what I want:

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/1996/13648488297821.jpg

The red line is the angles I want but the black line is the angles I get (black angles and above is all I can get, under the black line I can't do any rotation to get the wanted angle).

Please don't give me CSS Code since I'm using a JavaScript code loop

Comment: Can you fiddle it? I don't really understand the issue.

Comment: Include the code you're using to actually do the rotation, otherwise it's kinda hard to figure out what the issue is. All I see right now is code to draw a line

Comment: jsfiddle.net/2Yf7F - here you go, i already add it to bin website, you just didn't seen it cuz we were in chat room

Comment: @ExCluSiv3 Your fiddle still doesn't have any rotation code, so we still can't tell what's going wrong. Anyway, [here's a simple canvas animation](http://jsfiddle.net/zWdgt/) you might glean something from

Comment: Can you help me with my code? just for a example can you make me a vaild if number 8 statement? i didn't really got your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references from where I come up with this code can be found [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/), and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_moveto.asp). It is much easier if you split the line and make it into two with one after the other.
For example...

```
ctx.beginPath();
//edit the x or y to change starting point.
ctx.moveTo(50, 100);
//edit the x to change the length, and y for the angle.
//if you want a horizontal line this y must be the same as the moveto y.
ctx.lineTo(150, 100);

//This x & y must be the same as the previous lineto.
ctx.moveTo(150, 100);
//edit the x to change the length, and y for the angle.
ctx.lineTo(200, 130);
ctx.stroke();
```

Remember that the methods take (x,y) and as long as your first `lineTo` and next `moveTo` are the same positions you will not have a break in your two lines. Hope this helps!